# Should I feed my dog?

Tags: cooking-adventure

There is a dog named Willy on the street who I can give a bone to for 1000 dollars. This seems to make him happy but I don't see an in game benefit to it. Should I feed him? Do I get any sort of reward for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can get tickets to play in the lucky ball (lotto) game.. you can also get diamonds. The dog also gives a heart which I have not figured out. Most of the time, you'll get the colorful cans which don't have a value

Answer (score 1):

Feeding Willy, at a $1000 a piece, probably doesn't make up what you would get in exchange for the cans.  That's even if they still give money. The heart as far as I can see, and as previously stated, has no value whatsoever. You can get the lotto tickets and the diamonds, but they're not given except maybe every three to four times.

If you are low on cash. I'd say don't do it, especially if you are expecting a big pay day.  If you wanted to do it occasionally because it makes him happy, and as we know, it's all about making him happy. We are, after all, servants to our dogs.  They train us, not the other way around. LOL

I have over three million dollars so I feed him just to make him happy. When you get further along in the game money doesn't really matter much, so you can spend it kinda "Willy-Nilly" LOL.